# Exists in PostgreSQL not clear

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have difficulty in understanding what precisely EXISTS is doing in the following query,

```
select basket_a.* from basket_a where exists (select from basket_b where basket_b.fruit <> basket_a.fruit);
```

Why the output of the above query is whole of `basket_a`? `basket_a` contains

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
Cucumber
```

and `basket_b` contains

```
Orange
Apple
Watermelon
Pear
```

The difficulty stems from my half understanding of an analogues query

```
select basket_a.* from basket_a where exists (select from basket_b where basket_b.fruit = basket_a.fruit);
```

Output:

Apple
Orange

I assume the subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows. So, 
**basket_b.fruit = basket_a.fruit** returns two rows

Apple
Orange

which is more than **at least one row**. Thus **where exists** evaluates to true for these two rows and since it evaluates to false for the other two rows that do not match. Therefore, the matching rows from basket_a are selected. Am I correct here in terms of my understanding? If so, **basket_b.fruit <> basket_a.fruit** returns

Watermelon
Pear

Again, the subquery returns two rows. Unfortunately, Watermelon and Pear is not present in basket_a, does that mean the result of `where EXISTS` is false and `select * from basket_a` should return all rows? Is that how `EXISTS` is supposed to behave?

Comment: It would help if you clearly specify what you expect to get and what you actually get for each query.

Comment: if my understanding is correct then the query `select basket_a.* from basket_a where exists (select from basket_b where basket_b.fruit = basket_a.fruit);` should return Apple and Orange, the two matching rows. However, if I change the *where* condition to *basket_b.fruit != basket_a.fruit*. I am not sure what to expect. Any clarity in this matter would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is misunderstanding what EXISTS does. It never returns a column value, it always returns a single BOOLEAN value. And that boolean is determined by the where condition on the sub-select. The instant that is true processing of the sub-select terminates and returns true. Repeated if necessary for each row in the outer query.

```
  pseudo code  
    for each element in ba
        for each element in bb
            if ba.element OPER bb.element 
               return true               
        end for
    end for 
    return false
  end pseudo code
```

For actual examples see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q7JrD3b2UodqiahjxSxwwF/0). Especially note the 3rd query which actually test EXISTS where elements are different for the same set, NOT a set with the same values but actually the same set.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, that:

```
select basket_a.* from basket_a where not exists (select from basket_b where basket_b.fruit = basket_a.fruit);
```

is not the same as:

```
select basket_a.* from basket_a where exists (select from basket_b where basket_b.fruit <> basket_a.fruit);
```

The latter results in every row, because there exists a row in `basket_b`, that is not equal to the current row in `basket_a`. What you're looking for is the former query.

Comment: I got your point about the 'not' and it is important. I am not able to understand why the latter query should return all the rows of basket_a?

Comment: @Sowmya consider some row from `basket_a`, for example: `Apple`. There exists a row in `basket_b`, that is different, for example `Orange`. The same applies to other fruits in `basket_a`

Comment: @Androcious thanks for the pretty edits. I think the subquery `select from basket_b where basket_b.fruit <> basket_a.fruit` should return  Watermelon and Pear, which I understand is different from all of basket_a.

Comment: @Sowmya I'll say that once again. You're not selecting fuits that are different from all in `basket_b`, you're selecting the ones, that are different from any...